# C++ string - how to swap a string with two characters?

Tags: c++

Given a C++ string, str("ab"), how do I swap the content of str so that it becomes "ba"?

Here is my code:

```
string tmpStr("ab");

const char& tmpChar = tmpStr[0];
tmpStr[0] = tmpStr[1];
tmpStr[1] = tmpChar;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why it becomes `"bc"` not `"ba"`?

Comment: Thank you for the comments and I have corrected my question.

Comment: you have a stray `&` in your code, which means that it doesn't swap the characters. It sets them both equal to the second one.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I don't know that it's a "stray" &, I'd call that an outright error.  One related to "overly clever swapping".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Like this:

```
std::swap(tmpStr[0], tmpStr[1]);
```

`std::swap` is located in `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a sledgehammer for this nut:

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string value("ab");
reverse(value.begin(), value.end());
```

This one might be useful for the followup question involving "abc", though `swap` is preferred for the two-element case.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, std::swap would be the right thing to do here, as GMan pointed out. But let me explain the problem with your code:

```
string tmpStr("ab");
const char& tmpChar = tmpStr[0];
tmpStr[0] = tmpStr[1];
tmpStr[1] = tmpChar;
```

tmpChar is actually a reference to tmpStr[0]. So, this is what will happen:

```
| a | b |  (initial content, tmpChar refers to first character)
| b | b |  (after first assignment)
```

Note, that since tmpChar refers to the first character, it now evaluates to 'b' and the second assignment does effectivly nothing:

```
| b | b |  (after second assignment)
```

If you remove the & and make tmpChar an actual character variable, it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this :)

```
tmpStr[0] ^= tmpStr[1];
tmpStr[1] ^= tmpStr[0];
tmpStr[0] ^= tmpStr[1];
```

Explanation:

```
The XOR operator has the property: (x^y)^y = x
Let's we have a,b:

1 => a^b,b
2 => a^b,b^a^b=a
3 => a^b^a=b,a

The result is b,a.
```

Comment: Don't actually do this. It's slower on modern CPU's, and ugly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the characters one by one use an revers iterator as shown [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rbegin/)

```
// string::rbegin and string::rend
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str ("now step live...");
  string::reverse_iterator rit;
  for ( rit=str.rbegin() ; rit < str.rend(); rit++ )
    cout << *rit;
  return 0;
}
```

hth

Mario

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
std::string s("ab");

s[0] = 'b';
s[1] = 'c';
```

Or

```
std::string s("ab");

s = std::string("bc");
```

Comment: Hello rubenvb,  Sorry for my typo and thank you for your answer.

Comment: @ybungalobill - OP's code is clear enough even if text is (or was) not.

Comment: @ybunaglobill:  "how do I swap the content of str"  seems quite clear to me.