# Weird results with swap and substr functions

Tags: c++, swap, substr

I was trying to solve solve questions at [TopCoder](http://www.topcoder.com/). I was getting weird results on test sections of TopCoder; however, when I submit my code I got AC(stands for accepted). The case was the same on TCHS SRM 47 Level one - 250 pt - [Cards Shuffle](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=8295&rd=10803). I used [swap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3927212/2948746) function, my [code](http://ideone.com/LzIRaj)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int f, l, t;
    string c;
    cin>>c;
    scanf("%d%d%d", &f, &l, &t);
    //while(t--) c=c.substr(f-1, l-f+1)+c.substr(0, f-1)+c.substr(l);
    while(t--) for(int i=0, j=f-1; j<=l-1; i++, j++) swap(c[i], c[j]);
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

returns WA(stands for wrong answer) on test section of TC(stands for TopCoder), and AC when submitted on TC. Then I checked the code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/), with both [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) and swap functions respectively. On first try substr function gave expected result, while swap function unexpected result. However, on second try it was vice versa. I dont know what is going on, whether my code has a bug, or ideone, or TopCoder testing system.

Comment: Please give us a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Maybe because of [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)? Without code (relevant bits only please) it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @Tavian Barnes I used <a href=""></a> codes there, but after posting I found out that did not work. Sorry.

Comment: Your `swap` version definitely is wrong, it doesn't maintain the relative position of the old (1) and the old (f-1).

Comment: BTW, the function you should be using is `std::rotate`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt can you pls provide correct code, because im a noob. thnx

Comment: @Ben Voigt seems like rotate is applied to vectors: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/ & http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `std::rotate(c.begin(), c.begin() + ((f-1)*t % l), c.begin() + l);` should do the trick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58301/discussion-between-garakchy-and-ben-voigt).

Comment: What do you mean by unexpected results? What is your sample input? What are the expected results for the sample input?

Comment: Thanks to @BenVoigt the code below works on all testcases and AC when submitted: [code] 'code' string shuffle(string c, int f, int l, int t) {
    std::rotate(c.begin(), c.begin() + ((f-1)*t % l), c.begin() + l);
    return c;'
} 'code' [code]

Comment: @RSahu actually you would need TC arena for testcases, compile, submit, etc. anyway, for testcases: http://ideone.com/siTBjo

Answer (score 1):

**Your Algorithm**

Your algorithm using `swap` is faulty. Let's walk through the steps for one iteration of the `while` loop. You have:

```
for ( int i = 0; j = f-1; j <= l-1; ++i, ++i )
   swap(c[i], c[j]);
```

I don't know why you are using `f`, `l`, and `t`. It will be so much easier to read if you use `first`, `last`, and `times`.

```
for ( int i = 0; j = first-1; j <= last-1; ++i, ++i )
   swap(c[i], c[j]);
```

Let's use the following input:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ
5 6 1
```

In the first iteration of the `for` loop,

```
i = 0;
j = 4;
```

after the swap, the new value of `c` is

```
EBCDAFGHIJ (A and E are swapped)
```

In the second iteration of the `for` loop,

```
i = 1;
j = 5;
```

after the swap, the new value of `c` is

```
EFCDABGHIJ (B and F are swapped)
```

The iteration stops here since the value of `j` becomes `6`.

What you needed to end up with is:

```
EFABCDGHIJ
```

**A Different Algorithm**

If you want to minimize the number of strings created, you can use the following strategy.

For the given inputs, create the sub-string "EF" and store it. Then move "ABCDE" to the right by two. Then move "EF" to the start of the string. The following function does that. It changes `c` in place.

```
void fun(string& c, int first, int last)
{
   // Convert first to a 0-based index for easier manipulation.
   --first;

   int delta = last-first;
   string c1 = c.substr(first, delta);
   for ( int i = first-1; i >= 0; --i )
   {
      c[i+delta] = c[i];
   }

   for ( int i = 0; i < delta; ++i )
   {
      c[i] = c1[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: thnx for your answer. I would handle this specific TC question with rotate or substr or looking for other coders' AC codes. however, there is a bug in TC. after solving this question i moved further on TC, and tried another questions also, and realized that whatever i return as answer i got AC. thank you for your answer and for your time, sir. btw, how can i close my post on SO?

Comment: I am not sure you can close the post. You can delete it if you think it's not valuable.